# Angular.js HTTP request fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, google-chrome, http

I'm very new to web development so I need help.
I'd like to send an HTTP request to a web server to get some data. To authorise the user I have to send a secret in the user agent header.

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://my-website/some_data',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'User-Agent': 'service/2.0 (Android 4.3) sec=secret_key'
        }

     }).success(function(data){
        $scope.locations = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
    });
```

The problem is Chrome always prints:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
```

and:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
https://my-website/some_data. No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://127.XXXXX' is therefore not allowed
access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Did you tryed removing 'User-Agent'?

Comment: How should i remove it? If I just write 'service/2.0 (Android 4.3) sec=secret_key' I get a syntax error

Comment: Why are you setting this 'User-Agent': 'service/2.0 (Android 4.3) sec=secret_key' on first place?

Comment: I have no reason for that. Does the order matter?

Comment: It's not order, try removing that line of code and check is it working.

Comment: I need that line to authorise the user because of the secret in it. Otherwise it doesn't work. If I use a user agent switcher and set the header value it works fine.

Comment: then you need this type of header 
headers: {'Authorization': 'secret_key'}